# Change of variables mixing dependent and independent variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a system of two ordinary differential equations with two independent variables: $x,y$. And only dependent variable: $t$

Can I make the following change of variables: $t=ay$, such that the equation in $y$ turns into an algebraic equation and there remains only one differential equation in $x$ now depending on $y$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sadly no. In general there's no reason to believe that the solution would have $t=a y$ so you can't just assume this to be the case.

Comment: of course! thanks!